# How to use SetMenuInfom, changing the text of the menubar

Tags: c, winapi

I want present the number of mouse clicks in a window, on its menu bar.
Writing the count on the window is no problem, and but regarding the menu bar, I wonder if I am on the right track, it doesn't work, but I am using the correct functions, I think. Am doing some big misstake?
 I am doing the following inside of WinProc

```
  char buffer1[33] = "              ";

case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    xpos = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
    ypos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
    count++;
    MENUITEMINFO mii;
    HMENU hMenu = GetMenu(hwnd);
    mii.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
    mii.fMask = MIIM_TYPE | MIIM_ID;
    wsprintf( mii.dwTypeData, _itoa(count, buffer1,10));
    SetMenuItemInfo(hMenu,mii.wID,FALSE, &mii);

    RedrawWindow(hwnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_ERASE | RDW_INVALIDATE);
    break;
```

Comment: You're not setting `mii.dwTypeData` to point to anything.

Comment: do you have to use this monster? maybe do it in C# with wifforms or go for Qt

Comment: @Jonathan Potter
I am writing to mii.dwTypeData using wsprintf; don't I?
tinky_winky: It is an assignement :), still a student...

Comment: @LasseKaragiannis Yes but `dwTypeData` is just a pointer; at the moment an uninitialised one. You can't just write blindly to a pointer, it needs to point somewhere first.

Comment: can't believe they teach this awful API at university, amazing!

Comment: you are not setting `mii.fType`, either. Setting the `MIIM_TYPE` flag tells the menu that `mii.dwTypeData` has data assigned, but it is `mii.fType` that specifies what kind of data `mii.dwTypeData` has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with this code.

You are not assigning an allocated buffer to `mii.dwTypeData` for `wsprintf()` to write to.  `_itoa()` is writing to an allocated buffer, so just use that as-is, don't use `wsprintf()` at all.

You are not assigning anything to `mii.fType`, which tells the menu what type of data is assigned to `mii.dwTypeData`.

You are enabling the `MIIM_ID` flag, but you are not assigning anything to `mii.wID`.

In fact, your entire `mii` variable initially contains random data, so `fType`, `dwTypeData`, and `wID` will have random values that will make the menu misinterpret the data.  You need to zero out fields you are not using.  It is common practice to always zero out structures before passing them to Win32 API functions.

Try something more like this instead:

```
  char buffer1[33] = "              ";

case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
{
    xpos = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
    ypos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
    count++;
    MENUITEMINFOA mii;
    ZeroMemory(&mii sizeof(mii));
    mii.cbSize = sizeof(mii);
    mii.fMask = MIIM_FTYPE | MIIM_STRING | MIIM_ID;
    mii.fType = MFT_STRING;
    mii.dwTypeData = _itoa(count, buffer1, 10);
    mii.cch = strlen(mii.dwTypeData);
    mii.wID = ...; // your desired menu ID
    HMENU hMenu = GetMenu(hwnd);
    SetMenuItemInfoA(hMenu, mii.wID, FALSE, &mii);

    RedrawWindow(hwnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_ERASE | RDW_INVALIDATE);
    break;
}
```

Since you are merely setting the menu item text, you could alternatively use `ModifyMenu()` instead, which has simpler parameters to work with:

```
  char buffer1[33] = "              ";

case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
{
    xpos = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
    ypos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
    count++;
    HMENU hMenu = GetMenu(hwnd);
    UINT wID = ...; // your desired menu ID
    ModifyMenuA(hMenu, wID, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_STRING, 0, _itoa(count, buffer1, 10));

    RedrawWindow(hwnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_ERASE | RDW_INVALIDATE);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've also found these two methods:
 `_itow_s(count, buffer, 10);`
`wcscpy_s(szTitle, buffer);`
`SetWindowTextW(hWnd, szTitle);`
and
`SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)szTitle);`

Comment: How do I extract the menu Id mii.wID ? I have no resource file etc. Could you point me to a tutorial on fMask, and MF_BYCOMMAND and the other way that is indexed based? I found it difficult to understand the MSDN documentation on this.

Answer (score 2):

> wsprintf function
>
> [Writes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550(v=vs.85).aspx)
>   formatted data to the specified buffer.
>
> int __cdecl wsprintf(   *Out* LPTSTR  lpOut,   *In*  LPCTSTR lpFmt,
>   *In*          ... );

The description says that the `wsprintf` will **write** to the buffer which is the first argument given to it. This means this buffer **must** be good memory, that is allocated and available to you.

Solution:

Please initialize the pointer `mii.dwTypeData`.

---

btw: Microsoft only knows why in their docs synopsis of the function is given after description, uh.

Comment: The description of a function given on MSDN that is above the synopsis is a short one-sentence introduction to the function. It is no different from [a man page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/3c/wsprintf/). It is also no different from [the C# documentation for a method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) [or property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Happy helping! No need to be vicious.

Comment: @andlabs did you look at link you've posted? man provides only Name before synopsis, Name is not description as is in MSDN case, I have shortened it to one sentence intentionally